# Does whether a variable needs to be quoted or not depend on if the category in the database is marked as varchar or int?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example, say my query is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM statements WHERE user_id_created_by=$users_id";
```

Does whether $user_id need to be quoted or not depend on if the category in the database is marked as varchar or int?

Also, I don't quite understand whether or not spacing affects querys:

Is this the same as the one above:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM statements WHERE user_id_created_by = $users_id";
```

Comment: You can always use quotes, for both data types, but the very best thing to do would be using PDO or mysqli and prepared statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a variable in a query at all. Use prepared statements to prevent sql injection, which could allow an attacker to steal/modify/delete anything they want.

**PDO prepared statement (with named parameters):**

```
$params = [
  ':id' => $users_id
]
$query = "SELECT * FROM statements WHERE user_id_created_by=:id";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array($params);
```

**mysqli prepared statement:**

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM statements WHERE user_id_created_by=?")
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $users_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Regarding the spaces in a query, those shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

First: Use PDO and prepared statements as **m59** says!

The thing with the quotes is the following:
Imagine a varchar with spaces like `"this is an example"`.

The query unquoted query would than look like:

```
SELECT * FROM statements WHERE user_id_created_by=this is an example
```

(I guess) mysql will then think `is an example` doesnt belong to the passed varchar.